# How many groups consisting of 4 members can be made with b,c,d if they can be repeated?

Tags: combinatorics

How many groups of b,c and d can I make if they can be repeated? Eg. {bbcd},{bbcc},{cdcc},{cccc} etc.
Pls specify the no.of b's in a specific kind of group such as {bbdc} has two b's

Comment: What about ordering? Are bbcb and bbbc different groups?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are three choices for each of the four positions, there are $3^4 = 81$ ordered strings of length $4$ that can be formed by the three letters $b$, $c$, and $d$.

If you are instead interested in multi-sets (in which the order of the string does not matter), you have

- three ways to form a multi-set using one letter four times ($bbbb$, $cccc$, $dddd$)
- six ways to form a multi-set using one letter three times since there are three choices for the repeated letter and two choices for the other letter ($bbbc$, $bbbd$, $bccc$, $cccd$, $bddd$, $cddd$)
- three ways to form a multi-set using two letters twice each since there are $\binom{3}{2}$ choices of the letters ($bbcc$, $bbdd$, $ccdd$)
- three ways to form a multi-set using all three letters with one letter repeated twice since there are three ways to select the letter that is repeated ($bbcd$, $bccd$, $bcdd$)

Hence, there are $3 + 6 + 3 + 3 = 15$ possible multi-sets with $4$ elements that can be formed from the letters $b$, $c$, and $d$.